# How the swagger works in java backend?

Tags: java, swagger

I am a frontend developer. The backend developer left his job. So, I will also work on the backend part. I do not have any experience in the backend development. I am analyzing the backend code. I have few questions. I would like to clear my concepts.

I have attached the Java code file.

**1- What are these imports for?:**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModel;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty;
```

2- why we put **@JsonProperty** before declaring each variable?

**3- why we put class name in few methods? such as:**

```
public LedgerAccountRequestDto taxRateId(String taxRateId) {
  this.taxRateId = taxRateId;
  return this;
}
```

**4- What is the use of:**

```
 @ApiModel(description = "transaction request")
 @Validated**
```

**5- What is the use of:**

```
 @ApiModelProperty(required = true, value = "")
 @NotNull
```

**6- What is hashCode() method actually doing?**

```
 public int hashCode() {
   return Objects.hash(name, number, typeId, taxRateId);
}
```

Please help me in understanding these concepts. Thank you very much

```
    package com.kin.account.api.ledgerAccount.model;

    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
    import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModel;
    import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty;
    import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;

    import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
    import java.util.Objects;

    /**
     * transaction request
     */
    @ApiModel(description = "transaction request")
    @Validated
    public class LedgerAccountRequestDto   {
      @JsonProperty("name")
      private String name = null;

      @JsonProperty("number")
      private String number = null;

      @JsonProperty("typeId")
      private String typeId = null;

      @JsonProperty("taxRateId")
      private String taxRateId = null;

      public LedgerAccountRequestDto name(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
      }

      /**
       * Get name
       * @return name
      **/
      @ApiModelProperty(required = true, value = "")
      @NotNull

      public String getName() {
        return name;
      }

      public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
      }

      public LedgerAccountRequestDto number(String number) {
        this.number = number;
        return this;
      }

      /**
       * Get number
       * @return number
      **/
      @ApiModelProperty(required = true, value = "")
      @NotNull

      public String getNumber() {
        return number;
      }

      public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
      }

      public LedgerAccountRequestDto typeId(String typeId) {
        this.typeId = typeId;
        return this;
      }

      /**
       * Get typeId
       * @return typeId
      **/
      @ApiModelProperty(required = true, value = "")
      @NotNull

      public String getTypeId() {
        return typeId;
      }

      public void setTypeId(String typeId) {
        this.typeId = typeId;
      }

      public LedgerAccountRequestDto taxRateId(String taxRateId) {
        this.taxRateId = taxRateId;
        return this;
      }

      /**
       * Get taxRateId
       * @return taxRateId
      **/
      @ApiModelProperty(required = true, value = "")
      @NotNull

      public String getTaxRateId() {
        return taxRateId;
      }

      public void setTaxRateId(String taxRateId) {
        this.taxRateId = taxRateId;
      }


      @Override
      public boolean equals(java.lang.Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
          return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
          return false;
        }
        LedgerAccountRequestDto ledgerAccountRequestDto = (LedgerAccountRequestDto) o;
        return Objects.equals(this.name, ledgerAccountRequestDto.name) &&
            Objects.equals(this.number, ledgerAccountRequestDto.number) &&
            Objects.equals(this.typeId, ledgerAccountRequestDto.typeId) &&
            Objects.equals(this.taxRateId, ledgerAccountRequestDto.taxRateId);
      }

      @Override
      public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(name, number, typeId, taxRateId);
      }

      @Override
      public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("class LedgerAccountRequestDto {\n");
        
        sb.append("    name: ").append(toIndentedString(name)).append("\n");
        sb.append("    number: ").append(toIndentedString(number)).append("\n");
        sb.append("    typeId: ").append(toIndentedString(typeId)).append("\n");
        sb.append("    taxRateId: ").append(toIndentedString(taxRateId)).append("\n");
        sb.append("}");
        return sb.toString();
      }

      /**
       * Convert the given object to string with each line indented by 4 spaces
       * (except the first line).
       */
      private String toIndentedString(java.lang.Object o) {
        if (o == null) {
          return "null";
        }
        return o.toString().replace("\n", "\n    ");
      }
    }
```

Comment: IMHO, you'd be better served by looking at the docs for those libraries. SpringFramework, Jackson, and Swagger.

Comment: It would be better if they were separate questions.

Comment: IMHO if you're now both a backend and frontend developer, you should ask for your salary to be doubled.

Comment: `hashCode()` is explained in [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()), about #3 google method return type, and maybe search some guides, maybe for beginners, that's somewhat basic stuff.

Comment: I have posted a detailed explanation for you, I hope it helps. Take note of the `advice` section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to make this very simple and take you step by step

## 1. What are these `imports` for?:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
```

To import java package into a class, we need to use java import keyword which is used to access package and its classes into the java program. Use import to access built-in and user-defined packages into your java source file so that your class can refer to a class that is in another package by directly using its name. So using the above example `import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty`, that line imports the `JsonProperty` annotation from the jackson library.

## 2 Why use `@JsonProperty` before declaring each variable?

```
@JsonProperty
```

The @JsonProperty annotation is used to map property names with JSON keys during serialization and deserialization. By default, if you try to serialize a POJO, the generated JSON will have keys mapped to the fields of the POJO. If you want to override this behavior, you can use the @JsonProperty annotation on the fields. It takes a String attribute that specifies the name that should be mapped to the field during serialization.

## 3 Why we use class names in methods? such as:

```
public LedgerAccountRequestDto taxRateId(String taxRateId) {
    this.taxRateId = taxRateId;
    return this;
}
```

The above is a `setter` method called `narrated` with type `LedgerAccountRequestDto`. It's just the same as having a similar example with the type String. In the code above, the method returns the class instance as the return type.

## 4 What is the use of:

```
 @ApiModel(description = "transaction request")
 @Validated**
```

`@ApiModel` is a `Swagger` annotation.

> `Swagger` is the standard way of documenting the Standard APIs. Swagger is helpful when deploying APIs in azure. Swagger is primarily used for documenting API. for the other developers to be able to use the API, the API must be properly documented; otherwise, how would they know that what are the endpoints exposed by the api and what are the operations supported on those endpoints? What parameters should they pass, and what will they get back? What authentication methods to use?. To answer these questions, it is very important to document the APIs; if you want APIs to be consumed and properly used. To learn more about `Swagger`, check [Swagger - Javatpoint](https://www.javatpoint.com/swagger) and [Swagger - Github repo](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Annotations)

1. **`@ApiModel`** - Provides additional information about Swagger models. Swagger-core builds the model definitions based on the references to them throughout the API introspection. The @ApiModel allows you to manipulate the metadata of a model from a simple description or name change to a definition of polymorphism.
2. `@Valid` and `@Validated` Annotations - In Spring, we use JSR-303's `@Valid` annotation for method level validation. We also use it to mark a member attribute for validation. However, this annotation doesn't support `group validation`.

   > Groups help to limit the constraints applied during validation. One particular use case is UI wizards. In the first step, we may have a certain sub-group of fields. In the subsequent step, there may be another group belonging to the same bean. So we need to apply constraints on these limited fields in each step, but @Valid doesn't support this.

- In this case, for group-level, we have to use Spring's `@Validated`, which is a variant of `JSR-303's @Valid`.  This is used at the method level. For marking member attributes, we continue to use the `@Valid` annotation.

## 5 What is the use of:

```
@ApiModelProperty(required = true, value = "")
@NotNull
```

- `@ApiModelProperty` - In Swagger, this Adds and manipulates data of a model property. The @ApiModelProperty allows controlling Swagger-specific definitions such as allowed values, and additional notes. It also offers additional filtering properties in case you want to hide the property in certain scenarios.
- The `required` parameter specifies if the parameter is required or not. The `value` parameter defines a brief description of this property.

- The `@NonNull` is a common Spring annotation to declare that annotated elements cannot be null. It denotes that a parameter, field, or method return value can never be null. This is a marker annotation and it has no specific attributes.

## 6 What is `hashCode()` method actually doing?

```
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(name, number, typeId, taxRateId);
}
```

The hashCode method is an inbuilt method that returns the integer hashed value of the input value. To properly understand `hashCode()` and `equals()` using examples, check out [HashCode() in Java - scaler.com](https://www.scaler.com/topics/hashcode-in-java/) and also [What is the hashCode method in Java? - educative.io](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/what-is-the-hashcode-method-in-java)

## ADVICE

You have to learn Java if you don't have the basics, researching this way will be so difficult. Check the below resource links to learn Java and Spring boot.

### Learn Java

1. Notes  - [Learn Java - By Jakob Jenkov](https://jenkov.com/tutorials/java/index.html)
2. Videos - [Learn Java - By Java Guides](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ejaQ209nFfY&list=PLGRDMO4rOGcOlR-f9gaNlYZ6O3F_n6wIq)

### Learn Spring Boot

1. Notes  - [Learn SpringBoot - By Javatpoint](https://www.javatpoint.com/spring-boot-tutorial)
2. Videos - [Learn SpringBoot - By Java Guides](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jj2rNQuLEbg&list=PLGRDMO4rOGcOKUURLsVMKZbCZhZJNtEwW)

Comment: Please use titles/h1 tags/big fonts sparingly